# Waiting/syncing for result of a test method between 2 tests

Tags: android, kotlin, testing, testng, appium-android

I am attempting to UI test an application between two devices. I have two tests defined with the same number of test methods in a given test class in a TestNG xml file:

```xml
<test name="Samsung Device">
    <parameter>...</parameter>
    ...
    <classes>
        <class name="messageTest">
            <methods>
                ...
                <include name="Send a message"></include>
                ...
            </methods>
        </class>
    </classes>
</test>

<test name="Sony Device">
    <parameter>...</parameter>
    ...
    <classes>
        <class name="messageTest">
            <methods>
                ...
                <include name="Receive a message"></include>
                ...
            </methods>
        </class>
    </classes>
</test>
```

When tested in Appium, is it possible for "Receive a Message" test method to wait for "Send a Message" test method to finish or if very possible, finish simultaneously? If so, how will it be achieved. The expected results - when the solution is implemented - will be:

> "Send a message" will pass if message is sent successfully

> "Receive a message" will pass if message is received successfully

The initial solution was using implicit wait as provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70807534/15907167) but the solution doesn't really work. If it would work, it will also affect other sync-sensitive test methods between two different test devices.